# How to deal with mixed constructor parameters when registering types in asp.net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

> I'm wondering how to deal with dependency injection in ASP.NET Core
> for types that have both objects and strings as  parameters. As strings can't be registered to the DI framework I'm
> currently using an implementationfactory *and* use the service locator
> pattern, is there another way ? Is there something like Autofac's .WithParamenter for named parameters ?

Asp.net core DI makes it easy (and clean) to register a type to the DI framework for types with arguments that are already registered to the DI framework.

Given the following three constructors   :

```
  public MyStateService() { /* .... */ }
  public MyServiceBackend(IMyStateService state) { /* .... */}
  public MyServiceClient(IMyStateService state, IMyServiceBackend backend, string logConfigPath) { /*.... */ }
```

The first two types are easily registered to the DI container as follows :

```
  services.AddScoped<IMyStateService , MyStateService>();
  services.AddScoped<IMyServiceBackend, MyServiceBackend>();
```

For the third however, I had to use an implementationfactory *and* use the service locator pattern to get the first two types to inject.

```
  services.AddScoped<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceClient>((ctx) =>
  {
      IMyStateService state= ctx.GetRequiredService<IMyStateService >();
      IMyServiceBackend backend = ctx.GetRequiredService<IMyServiceBackend>();
      return new MyServiceClient(state, backend, _serilogConfigPath);
  });
```

My technical project goes nuts on seeing a service locator [anti-pattern ] and demands a solution without service locator.
If we were using *Autofac* we could use the ***.WithParameter()*** for named parameters, but dotnet core di doesn't have that, does it ?
Is there another elegant way ?

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of [`ActivatorUtilities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateInstance__1_System_IServiceProvider_System_Object___),

```
public static T CreateInstance<T> (IServiceProvider provider, params object[] parameters);
```

Which

> Instantiate a type with constructor arguments provided directly and/or from an IServiceProvider.

```
//...

services.AddScoped<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceClient>((provider) => {
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyServiceClient>(provider, _serilogConfigPath);      
}); 

//...
```

In the above example the provider will be used to resolve the other dependencies while string parameter will be provided directly.

If the target class can be refactored then do not explicitly depend on the string. Consider using the Options pattern

Reference: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

Create a concrete class to store the desired data

```
public class LogConfigOPtions {
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Refactor the target class to depend on that

```
//...
string string logConfigPath;

//ctor
public MyServiceClient(IMyStateService state, IMyServiceBackend backend, IOptions<LogConfigOPtions> options) { 

    logConfigPath = options.Value.Path;

    //...
 }
```

And finally, configure options accordingly when registering services

```
//...

services.Configure<LogConfigOPtions>(option => {
    option.Path = _serilogConfigPath;
});
services.AddScoped<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceClient>();
services.AddScoped<IMyStateService , MyStateService>();
services.AddScoped<IMyServiceBackend, MyServiceBackend>();

//...
```

Comment: Thanks a million !!! I glanced at ActivatorUtilities before but didn't realise it was this easy.. 
And yes, the Options pattern was the other alternative that I was actually already refactoring for. The options pattern didn't feel as good though because one could more easily overlook a null value